# combining (not a sql join) 2 spark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes that are large here are sample examples..

first

```
firstnames|lastnames|age
tom|form|24
bob|lip|36
....
```

second

```
firstnames|lastnames|age
mary|gu|24
jane|lip|36
...
```

I would like to take both dataframes and combine them into one that look like:

```
firstnames|lastnames|age
tom|form|24
bob|lip|36
mary|gu|24
jane|lip|36
...
```

now I could write them both out and them read them together but that's a huge waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both dataframes are identical in structure then it's straight forward -`union()`

```
df1.union(df2)
```

In case any dataframe have any missing column then you have add dummy column in that dataframe on that specific column position else union will throw column mismatch exception. in below example column 'c3' is missing in df1 so I am adding dummy column in df1 in last position.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df1.select('c1','c2',lit('dummy')).union(df2.select('c1','c2','c3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple as shown here : union https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/append-a-row-to-rdd-or-dataframe.html